# Calling an entity's setter for updating its column from a controller of another entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, relationship

I need to update the Client table's *budget* column after inserting a new Budget into the database, but it doesn't. This is how I am doing inside of `BudgetController::addAction()`:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $manager->persist($form->getData());
    $manager->flush();

    $Client = $manager->getReference('PanelBundle:Client', $form['client_id']->getData()->getId());
    $Client->setBudget($manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget')->getLastId());

    $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
}
```

The `$Client` declaration returns the Client name successfully, but the line where it sets the `setBudget()` seem not to work. I don't know how to make an update like this. I need it to update after inserting into Budget according to the selected Client id in Budget form.

Client and Budget are related to `oneToMany` and `manyToOne`, respectively, am I missing something because of this relationship?

Comment: May I know the paramaters for `setBudget`?

Comment: @kdlcruz The `setBudget()` is the setter method of the **Client** entity, not any custom function, like `getLastId()`, get it? It is an integer field to store the **Budget** (s) of each **Client**, after adding a new one.

Comment: ok, but if it's only the setter then where is the `->update()` or the `->save()` method that will update the client's budget or is that also included in the `setBudget`? Maybe `$Client->update()` or '$Client->save()` would fix your issue.

Comment: @kdlcruz Oh, I had written a function for this, but I was facing a Semantical Error thrown due to the query when executing the method, and also I was told it was a better idea to use OOP approach for this. If you want to, you can check my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441630/trying-to-update-one-table-after-inserting-into-another-one-with-symfony2-and-do). :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the Budget entity is a ManyToOne association of the Client, then you should be using `->addBudget()` instead of a setter.  It's also probably better to do a `->find()` for the Client entity instead of a `->getReference()`.  If you really want to save the extra trip to the database, use the setter on the Budget entity instead to set the `$client` proxy created by the `->getReference()`, i.e. `$budget->setClient($client);`.  But it's not that expensive to find the Client and it ensures that the Client of that id exists.  It would then also be a good idea to flush the manager again, just to make sure things are wrapped up cleanly, instead of assuming it will all happen without interruption as the kernel terminates.  A complete rendition of your controller and action should look something like this:

```
namespace PanelBundle\Controller;

use PanelBundle\Entity\Budget;
use PanelBundle\Form\Type\BudgetType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class BudgetController extends Controller
{
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $budget = new Budget();
        $budgetForm = $this->createForm(new BudgetType(), $budget);
        $budgetForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($budgetForm->isValid()) {
            $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $manager->persist($budget);
            $manager->flush();

            $client = $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Client')
                ->find($budgetForm->get('client_id')->getData())
            ;
            $client->addBudget($budget);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
        }

        return $this->render(
            'PanelBundle:Budget:add.html.twig',
            array(
                'budgetForm' => $budgetForm->createView(),
            )
        );
    }
}
```