# How to update an entity related to another one after inserting new data?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-update

I'm almost getting desperate. I have made this question few times hoping for new answers to come, but all of them did not help me. I have tried many times but I only get errors, based on these answers, but no success. I'm stuck at it for more than a week, and I have a limited time.

I have a table called **Client**, related to **Budget**. First, showing the `Client` entity:

```
class Client
{
    private $id;

    private $name;

    private $phone;

    private $email;

    private $streetName;

    private $district;

    private $number;

    private $city;

    private $zipCode;

    private $budget;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setStreetName($streetName)
    {
        $this->streetName = $streetName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStreetName()
    {
        return $this->streetName;
    }

    public function setDistrict($district)
    {
        $this->district = $district;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDistrict()
    {
        return $this->district;
    }

    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setZipCode($zipCode)
    {
        $this->zipCode = $zipCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZipCode()
    {
        return $this->zipCode;
    }

    function setBudget($budget)
    {
        $this->budget = $budget;
    }

    function getBudget()
    {
        return $this->budget;
    }
}
```

And now, the `Budget` entity:

```
class Budget
{
    private $id;

    private $clientId;

    private $address;

    private $installments;

    private $checkDays;

    private $dateStart;

    private $dateCreated;

    private $totalValue;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dateCreated = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setClientId(Client $clientId)
    {
        $this->clientId = $clientId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getClientId()
    {
        return $this->clientId;
    }

    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setInstallments($installments)
    {
        $this->installments = $installments;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInstallments()
    {
        return $this->installments;
    }

    public function setCheckDays($checkDays)
    {
        $this->checkDays = $checkDays;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCheckDays()
    {
        return $this->checkDays;
    }

    public function setDateStart($dateStart)
    {
        $this->dateStart = $dateStart;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateStart()
    {
        return $this->dateStart;
    }

    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->dateCreated = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->dateCreated;
    }

    public function setTotalValue($totalValue)
    {
        $this->totalValue = $totalValue;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalValue()
    {
        return $this->totalValue;
    }
}
```

Fine. Now, their relationship. First, the `Client.orm.yml`:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Client:
    type: entity
    table: client
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\ClientRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        phone:
            type: string
            length: 255
        email:
            type: string
            length: 255
        streetName:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: street_name
        district:
            type: string
            length: 255
        number:
            type: string
            length: 255
        city:
            type: string
            length: 255
        zipCode:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: zip_code
    oneToMany:
        budget:
            targetEntity: Budget
            mappedBy: clientId
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

And now, the `Budget.orm.yml`:

```
CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\Budget:
    type: entity
    table: budget
    repositoryClass: CDG\PanelBundle\Entity\BudgetRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        address:
            type: string
            length: 255
        installments:
            type: integer
        checkDays:
            type: integer
            column: check_days
        dateStart:
            type: datetime
            column: date_start
        dateCreated:
            type: datetime
            column: date_created
        totalValue:
            type: decimal
            column: total_value
            nullable: true
    manyToOne:
        clientId:
            targetEntity: Client
            inversedBy: budget
            joinColumn:
                name: client_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

So far so good. Explaining, I must update the field *budget* from **Client** entity right after inserting new data into **Budget**. For this, I have tried MANY different ways, erros, but sadly I don't remember all of them. If you feel like, please check my previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441630/trying-to-update-one-table-after-inserting-into-another-one-with-symfony2-and-do), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446559/calling-an-entitys-setter-for-updating-its-column-from-a-controller-of-another) and if you are Brazilian, [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85727/symfony2-atualizar-campo-de-uma-entidade-ao-executar-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-controller-de-out), to see the how I have tried to solve this.

Below is my current `BudgetController.php` and its `addAction()` method, used to persist the form data into **Budget** table. The way it is now gives no errors, but the *budget* field from **Client** is not updated.

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new BudgetType());
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $Client = $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Client');
    $Budget = $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget');

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $manager->persist($form->getData());
            $manager->flush();

            $Client = $manager->find('PanelBundle:Client', $form['client_id']->getData()->getId());
            $Client->setBudget($manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget')->getLastId());

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PanelBundle:Budget:add.html.twig', array(
        'clients' => $Client->findAll(),
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

If I try to persist the `$Client` and `flush()`, I get the error:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

I have written a function `addBudgetToClient()` in my `BudgetRepository.php`, that has two parameters, one for the selected **Client**, and other for the recently added **Budget** ids. Here it is:

```
public function addBudgetToClient($clientId, $budgetId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('PanelBundle:Client')
                ->update('PanelBundle:Client', 'c')
                ->set('c.budget', $budgetId)
                ->where('c.id = ' . $clientId)
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute();
}
```

Then, in my Controller, if I try:

```
$Budget->addBudgetToClient($form['client_id']->getData()->getId(), $Budget->getLastId());
```

I get the error:

> Semantical Error] line 0, col 34 near 'budget = 4 WHERE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
>
> [2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 34 near 'budget = 4 WHERE': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.  +
>
> [1/2] QueryException: UPDATE PanelBundle:Client c SET c.budget = 4 WHERE c.id = 3  +

The SQL seems right, then why?

It is many errors, many ways, but zero success. Thank you.

**EDITED**

As requested, my `getLastId()`:

```
public function getLastId()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
                ->select('MAX(b.id)')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Comment: I'm use odm, but I see that Client is not the owning side, you should do simply `$budget->setClient($client);` Query for client budgets is done by client reference field.

Comment: @malcolm I'm not sure if I get it. Is something wrong with my relationship?

Comment: Never mind, have no time to explain  :) Can you post your `getLastId()` repository method?

Comment: @malcolm I've edited my question. It just returns the largest ID. I've echoed it to test and works.

Comment: So why you use `getSingleScalarResult()` instead of `getSingleResult()` ? I'm not ORM familiar, but you must return object with this query, if you want to set it in controller as described.

Comment: @malcolm I use this function to return the ID of the last inserted Bundle to update the Client _budget_ field.

Comment: So you cannot return just ID, you must return FULL object to `$Client->setBudget` as you declared mapping to budget field to `OneTOMany`. This is causing the error you've got. Do you understand now: "expects parameter 1 to be object, string given" instead of object, you returned string (entity id).

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your entity in a wrong way. Instead, try this:

```
$budget = new Budget();
$form = $this->createForm(new BudgetType(), $budget, array("method" => "POST");

$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $manager->persist($budget);

    $client = $manager->find('PanelBundle:Client', $form['client_id']->getData()->getId());
    // do something if was not found
    $client->setBudget($budget);

    $manager->flush();

    $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
}
```

Comment: Hello, like this does not add to Budget, it simply reloads the form again. One thing I'm facing is that Client has `__toString()`. If I try to recover the object, an error saying that was expecting an Object to `persist`. If I remove the `__toString()`, an error says the object could not be converted to string.

Comment: @mfgabriel92 I'm sorry, it is hard to understand what u are talking about. The code that I've written works nice and should save all the data with relations.

Comment: I face several problems. First, the code you gave me somehow just reloads the form and nothing is added. Second, when I try to persist the `$client`, the error `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given` shows up, because its `__toString()` returns the name, but I must have it, otherwise I can't list it in the homepage. It's a #!@$ mess and I'm totally lost too.